# google карта Gmap.NET грузить офлайн версию

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди на winforms работает google MAP. нужно реализовать офлайн версию для нескольких пользователей через локальный сервер.  тоесть хочу Гугл карту грузить на сервер компьютер и через сервер с помощью winforms раздать пользователям. Скажите пожалуйста, как это реализуется ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ToolTips;

namespace LOCAL_PROJECT
{
public partial class maps : Form
{
    public maps()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   
    private void gMapControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        // Настройки для компонента GMap
        gmap.Bearing = 0;
        // Перетаскивание правой кнопки мыши
        gmap.CanDragMap = true;
        // Перетаскивание карты левой кнопкой мыши
        gmap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;

        gmap.GrayScaleMode = true;

        // Все маркеры будут показаны
        gmap.MarkersEnabled = true;
        // Максимальное приближение
        gmap.MaxZoom = 18;
        // Минимальное приближение
        gmap.MinZoom = 2;
        // Курсор мыши в центр карты
        gmap.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionWithoutCenter;

        // Отключение нигативного режима
        gmap.NegativeMode = false;
        // Разрешение полигонов
        gmap.PolygonsEnabled = true;
        // Разрешение маршрутов
        gmap.RoutesEnabled = true;
        // Скрытие внешней сетки карты
        gmap.ShowTileGridLines = false;
        // При загрузке 10-кратное увеличение
        gmap.Zoom = 20;
        // Изменение размеров
        // gmap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        // Чья карта используется
        gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;

        // Загрузка этой точки на карте
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(37.59166577825099, 61.84378218030843);

        // Создаём новый список маркеров
        GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");

        // Инициализация красного маркера с указанием его коордиант
        GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(37.59167129066048, 61.84377522351632), GMarkerGoogleType.red);
        marker.ToolTip = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ToolTips.GMapRoundedToolTip(marker);

        // Текст отображаемый с маркером
        marker.ToolTipText = "Enter";
        // Добавляем маркер в список маркеров
        markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
        gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);

        // Установка максимального, минимального и текущего значения элемента управления
     //   trackBar1.Maximum = 18;
   //     trackBar1.Minimum = 2;
    //    trackBar1.Value = (int)gmap.Zoom;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            //Инициализируем новую переменную класса SaveFileDialog,
            //открывающий диалоговое окно для сохранения файла. 
            using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                //Задаем текущую строку фильтра имен файлов,
                //которая определяет варианты, доступные в поле 
                //"Сохранить как тип файла" или "Файлы типа"
                //диалогового окна.                    
                dialog.Filter = "PNG (*.png)|*.png";

                //Задаем строку, содержащую имя файла,
                //выбранное в диалоговом  окне файла.
                dialog.FileName = "GMap.NET image";

                //Создаем новое изображение и
                //передаем компонент с картой.
                Image image = this.gmap.ToImage();

                if (image != null)
                {
                    using (image)
                    {
                        //Запускаем общее диалоговое окно с
                        //заданным по умолчанию владельцем.                          
                        //Данное окно возвращает объект
                        //System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK,
                        //если пользователь нажимает кнопку
                        //ОК в диалоговом окне; в противном случае 
                        //— объект System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel.
                        //Если пользователь нажал ОК, то идем дальше.
                        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            //Заносим в переменную имя файла введенное 
                            //в диалоговом окне.
                            string fileName = dialog.FileName;

                            //Выполняем проверку:
                            //был ли задан формат изображения карты,
                            //если нет, то добавляем после имени
                            //расширение файла.
                            if (!fileName.EndsWith(".png",
                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                fileName += ".png";
                            }
                            //Выполняем сохранение изображения карты.
                            image.Save(fileName);

                            //Выводим сообщение об успешном сохранении 
                            //и пути к данному изображению карты.
                            MessageBox.Show("Saved: "
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + dialog.FileName, "GMap.NET",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Если на одном из этапов сохранения произошла ошибка 
            MessageBox.Show("Error: "
                + Environment.NewLine
                + exception.Message,
                "GMap.NET",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Никак, потому что данные с гуглокарт нельзя скачать, они формируются в реальном времени чисто для показа. Даже если бы всю гуглокарту можно было бы скачать, вам пришлось бы построить большой шкаф с жесткими дисками (стоимостью железа больше, чем всё здание вместе взятое, в котором вы собрались организовать сервер), чтобы в него влезло всё, что имеется у гугла на карте. Вопрос из разряда "можно ли скачать весь интернет".

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста какой выход есть , дело в том что , только у одного компьютера-сервера есть доступ к интернету , у остальных компьютеров нету доступа в интернет.  а я собираюсь грузить только один небольшой город

Comment: Скажите админу, чтобы дал доступ в интернет. Это дешевле и проще. Офлайн карты существуют, но это не гугл.

Comment: мне непринципиально именно гугл, можно другие офлайн варианты.  главное условия без доступа к интернету